# Binding Interaction Trigger focus border

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a ListBox where the user can select an item and once he press the right arrow then that item is moved to another panel.

Things works when I use a button to raise the command; but  when I have the item and press the right arrow then the item is added but the focus in the next one is not properly set, I mean, the border is focused instead another item.

I've already set `IsTabStop="False"` on the ListBox.

This is how I'm binding the interaction trigger:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
        <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="WasPressed">
            <cal:Parameter Value="$eventArgs"/>
        </cal:ActionMessage>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

And this is how I'm managing the Trigger to Command raising:

```
public void WasPressed(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (SelectedItem != null && e.Key == Key.Right)
    {
        MoveItem();
    }
}
```

And this is how it looks after I pressed the right arrow (and the item is added, so it works). Notice the border that appear:

[image: After]

Answer (score 0):

Many WPF elements have a trigger on the IsFocused property, that adds a dotted border around it. It seems that this is happening here.

ListBox does not have such a trigger, so you should investigate parent elements.

The easiest way to do this is by editing the existing copy of the template using Blend.

Click on the element, the go on Object -> Edit Style -> Edit a Copy

Then Blend explicitly defines the template and you can look for triggers that define a dotted border.